# Regex pattern need for '?' and '=' | '=' and '&'

Tags: regex, preg-match

Regex pattern need to  for url parameters in bold color

http://example.com/XMLFeed?**clientkey**=abtc&**type**=Products&**ProductID**=111&**location**=145

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach to it, but really you should use a URL parsing library:

```
>>> s = "http://example.com/XMLFeed?clientkey=abtc&type=Products&ProductID=111&location=145"
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(\w+)=\w+', s)
['clientkey', 'type', 'ProductID', 'location']
```